# Wikipedia Layout: Text is too short for pictures in picture tutorial

Tags: image, layout, wikipedia

I would like to create a picture tutorial,[like suggested here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Picture_tutorial#On_the_right).

My current layout looks like the first picture.

[image: First Picture], but I want each subsection to have its own photo, like shown in the second picture, but I don't have much text in each section and don't want to manually fill the correct number of new lines to fill each section. Is there a better way?

[image: Second picture (altered screenshot)]

Answer (score 0):

Use `{{clear}}` at the end of each section.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Clear/doc